# find in nested array and print the corrosponding names

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I want to print the names of people when supplied the `did`.

I have used this to get the array :

```
$getdepts_another=mysqli_query($connection,
    "select did,name,photo,dabout,fname,lname 
     from dept 
     where (acid='1' and name !='Admin')"); 
$deparray=array(); 
while($res = mysqli_fetch_row($getdepts_another))
{ 
    array_push($deparray, $res); 
} 
$_SESSION['deps_array']=$deparray;
```

This is my array:

```
array(9) {
    [0]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(1) "2"
        [1]=> string(8) "Accounts"
        [2]=> string(29) "1851530771msstore_400x400.jpg"
        [3]=> string(0) ""
        [4]=> string(0) ""
        [5]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(1) "3"
        [1]=> string(14) "Human Resource"
        [2]=> string(9) "photo.png"
        [3]=> string(0) ""
        [4]=> string(0) ""
        [5]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(1) "4"
        [1]=> string(9) "Documents"
        [2]=> string(9) "photo.png"
        [3]=> string(0) ""
        [4]=> string(0) ""
        [5]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [3]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(1) "5"
        [1]=> string(5) "Sales"
        [2]=> string(9) "photo.png"
        [3]=> string(0) ""
        [4]=> string(0) ""
        [5]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [4]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(1) "6"
        [1]=> string(7) "General"
        [2]=> string(9) "photo.png"
        [3]=> string(0) ""
        [4]=> string(0) ""
        [5]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [5]=> array(6) {
        [0]=> string(1) "7"
        [1]=> string(10) "Marketting"
        [2]=> string(9) "photo.png"
        [3]=> string(0) ""
        [4]=> string(0) ""
        [5]=> string(0) ""
     }
```

And this is my function to search and print the names of `did`

```
function search($ids, $array) {

    $idArray = explode(",", $ids);
    $result = Array();

    foreach($idArray as $id)
    {

        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['did'] === $id) {
                echo "name:".$val['fame'];
                array_push($result, $val['fame']);
            }
        }

    }

    return $result;

}//end function

$res = search('3,6', $array);
```

If I use `search(1,2);` it should print `Accounts,Human Resource`.

Comment: you have no `did` key in your array, so your `if()` will never match ANYTHING.

Comment: i have used $getdepts_another=mysqli_query($connection,"select did,name,photo,dabout,fname,lname from dept where (acid='1' and name !='Admin')"); 
$deparray=array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_row($getdepts_another)){
        array_push($deparray, $res);
     }
    $_SESSION['deps_array']=$deparray; to get array

Comment: don't paste code into comments. it's totally unreadable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `search('2,3', $deparray)` to return `Accounts` and `Human Resources`?

Comment: The fact that this code could be real frightens me.

Comment: @Soana yes i am expecting this thing only .. but it dosent print this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row`. That may be why there are no assoc keys in the array to search for.

```
$getdepts_another=mysqli_query($connection, 
    "
    SELECT did,name,photo,dabout,fname,lname 
    FROM dept 
    WHERE (acid='1' and name !='Admin')
    "
); 
$deparray = array(); 
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdepts_another))
{ 
    array_push($deparray, $res); 
} 
$_SESSION['deps_array']=$deparray;
```

Secondly, in your search function, you are returing the key `fame` instead of `fname`.

```
function search($ids, $array) {

    $idArray = explode(",", $ids);
    $result = Array();

    foreach($idArray as $id)
    {

        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['did'] === $id) {
                echo "name:".$val['fname'];
                array_push($result, $val['fname']);
            }
        }

    }

    return $result;

}//end function

$res = search('3,6', $array);
```

Hope this helps.